# Go validator.v2 gives error "unknown tag" for regexp

Tags: regex, validation, go

I have been trying to understand why some regular expressions give me an error "Unknown tag" while using the [validator.v2](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/validator.v2) package in golang. It works for some regular expressions but does not work with some which have "{}" inside them, and when I use the validator.Validate() it gives me an error at runtime "unknown tag".

Here's the code:

```
type Company struct {
    Name string `validate:"regexp=^[a-zA-Z .]{1,100}$"` 
}
```

which gives me the following error at runtime:

```
Name: unknown tag
```

however this regex works perfectly fine

```
type Company struct {
    Name string `validate:"regexp=^[a-zA-Z .]*$"` 
}
```

I am using the braces because of length restrictions that I want to put on the string. There could be other ways to do it, but I feel the regex is the way to go and is easier to have it along with other rules right there in the expression.

Comment: Also, I tried escaping that "." in the regex, which did not give me the error "Unknown tag" but it just bypassed that validation. This could be a possible bug. GitHub [issue](https://github.com/go-validator/validator/issues/56)

Comment: Have you tried escaping the {}? `regexp=^[a-zA-Z .]\{1,100\}$`

Comment: @LukasIsselbächer Yes, escaping the braces does not help, it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the `,` char in your first regex.  You can see in the validator [source code](https://github.com/go-validator/validator/blob/v2/validator.go#L332) that the tag is split on `,`. By UTSLing, I see no support for escaped commas in the tags; this is probably an oversight on the part of the project author. I suggest filing a bug/feature request.

Comment: Yes, I have added the [issue](https://github.com/go-validator/validator/issues/57) on the project repo. Any other approach for struct field validations?

Answer (score 0):

The problem pointed out by @Flimzy is correct, but it's not a bug.

Probably it was fixed since then, so at the moment `validator` supports escape sequence `\\` for such case, and you can do it like this:

```
type Company struct {
    Name string `validate:"regexp=^[a-zA-Z .]{1\\,100}$"` 
}
```